# expo background push notfication in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, apple-push-notifications, expo

At first, I was worried that expo had a custom notification system (had me thinking "coulda had a p8", if you know the commercial like that, haha). In the end, I was impressed with how direct and easy sending messages with expo's push notification service is. The only problem I ran into was in coming to realize that this *will never work* on a simulator. Otherwise, it's pretty spiffy really, even easier than a p8.

But I'm noticing a different pattern of behavior when I try to send a background notification.  In that instance, nothing seems to be happening.

My platform is iOS, and my App component has an extension that it binds to `this` and then fires off only once:

## extensionAPNs.js

```js
import { Alert } from 'react-native'
import { Permissions, Notifications } from 'expo'
import AsyncStorage from '@callstack/async-storage'

import { handleNotification } from '@src/lib/APNs'

export async function registerForPushNotifications () {
  const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)

  if (status !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      Alert.alert('received no permission to listen to APNs')
      return
    }
  }

  const expoToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()
  Alert.alert('recieved permission to listen to APNs with token ' + expoToken)

  this.subscription = Notifications.addListener(handleNotification)

  this.setState({ expoToken })
  AsyncStorage.setItem('expoToken', expoToken)
}
```

```js
import { Alert } from 'react-native'

export async function handleNotification () {
  Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(arguments))
  console.log('arguments', arguments)
}
```

Elsewhere, I share that token so I can message it. I noticed it wasn't working when my server sent its background message, although it does register as a success from the POST (didn't open the app, didn't add the Alert popup... even if the app was in the foreground, no popup). So I went to the [PN tool](https://expo.io/dashboard/notifications) and sure enough, the first "hello world" that I did work. Immediately, it works, too.

But if I configure it like my own message, with JSON data, category, and content available -- **and nothing else**, nothing happens. Not in the foreground, not in the background. Not when closed. :frowning: